# How grpc-health-probe (gRPC health checking on Kubernetes) differentiates between liveness and readiness probes

Tags: grpc-java, kubernetes-health-check

I am writing one grpc service and using gRPC health checking on Kubernetes (https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-health-probe). In my server, I added different implementation (one for liveness and other for readiness) of endpoints. I am wondering how this probe utility binary differentiates between liveness check vs readiness check? There should be some other way to define it in yaml, not just
["bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8801"]

```
server = ServerBuilder.forPort(port)
  .addService(new GrpcModuleHealthCheck())
  .addService(new GrpcModuleReadinessCheck())
  .addService(ProtoReflectionService.newInstance())
  .build.start
```

In kubernetes deployment yaml, I am using below configurations

```
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      exec:
        command: ["bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8801"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 240
      periodSeconds: 20
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      exec:
        command: ["bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8801"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 20
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
```

I just tested and found "GrpcModuleReadinessCheck" (the health class which I added last) implementation is taking effect when I just exec my kubernetes pod

```
kubectl exec -it <MY_POD_NAME> -- /bin/bash

bash-4.4$ ./grpc_health_probe -addr=localhost:8801
status: SERVING
```

Answer (score 7):

> I am wondering how this probe utility binary differentiates between liveness check vs readiness check?

In short, it doesn't.

Kubernetes defines two distinct checks: [liveness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-command) to check whether the program is still working properly (i.e. did not hang) and [readiness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) to check whether the program is willing to accept more requests.

However, gRPC only defines a single [health checking protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) and does not have a native concept of "readiness check".

It is up to you how you want to map gRPC responses to Kubernetes checks. A reasonable way would be interpreting `SERVING` response as the service being alive and ready to accept more requests, `NOT SERVING` response as the service being alive but not accepting requests, and `UNKNOWN` or failure to respond as the service not being alive.

Here is the probe configuration implementing that:

```
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      exec:
        # considers both SERVING and NOT SERVING to be a success
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bin/grpc_health_probe -addr=:8801 2>&1 | grep -q SERVING"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 240
      periodSeconds: 20
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      exec:
        # fails on any response except SERVING
        command: ["bin/grpc_health_probe", "-addr=:8801"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 20
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
```